# filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient is not working in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I want to apply a gradient background color to my `div`.

For IE I have used the property:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fad59f', endColorstr='#fa9907')
```

It's working in IE9 and IE8. But not working in IE7.

What should I do to see in IE?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xRcXL/2/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Having seen your fiddle in the comments the issue is quite easy to fix. You just need to add `overflow:auto` or set a specific height to your `div`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/xRcXL/3/

```
.Tab{
    overflow:auto; /* add this */
    border:solid 1px #faa62a;
    border-bottom:none;
    padding:7px 10px;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FAD59F, #FA9907) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fad59f), to(#fa9907));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fad59f, endColorstr=#fa9907);    
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fad59f, endColorstr=#fa9907)";
}
```

Comment: zoom:1 will do the same but has "no" effect on the element. (This has just fixed the same problem for me after a couple of hours of swearing.)

Comment: For an explanation why this works - putting `overflow:auto`, forces the [hasLayout property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout) on the element

Comment: I needed to use `-ms-filter` instead of `filter` and wrap the `progid:DXImageTransform...` in quotation marks as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a `GradientType`:

```
background: #f0f0f0; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #eeeeee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#eeeeee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 100%); /* W3C */
```

source: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #fad59f, #fa9907) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fad59f), to(#fa9907));
/* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fad59f, #fa9907);
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fad59f, endColorstr=#fa9907);
/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fad59f, endColorstr=#fa9907)";
```

Otherwise generate using the following link and get the code.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/