# Dynamic change of gradient colors in all browsers

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a script where a user can set the gradient of a div by inputting color codes in two different text fields.

This is my code:

```
        <style>
        #gradient {
            background: #0A284B;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
    background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
    zoom: 1;    }  
    </style>


    <script>

    function myFunction()
    {
    color1 = document.getElementById("color1").value;
    color2 = document.getElementById("color2").value;

    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))";
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="-webkit-linear-gradient("+color1+", "+color2+")";
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="-moz-linear-gradient(top, "+color1+", "+color2+")";
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="-ms-linear-gradient("+color1+", "+color2+")";
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="-o-linear-gradient("+color1+", "+color2+")";
    document.getElementById("gradient").style.background="linear-gradient("+color1+", "+color2+")";
document.getElementById("gradient").style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(startColorstr='"+color1+"', endColorstr='"+color2+"')";

    }
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="color1" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="#E9EDF6"></input>
    <input type="text" id="color2" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="#AABBDD"></input>

    <div id="gradient" style="height:500px">
        I have gradient
    </div>
```

The function works fine in Firefox and IE10, but not in older IE versions.
I am guessing it's because the last background call overwrites the others which are meant for older IE versions.

So how would you go about this? 
Should I create a function which first checks the browser used before calling the color change function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the amazing [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

As you can see, it generate more code than what you do, with comments at the end of each line indicating which browsers are affected by that line:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Specifically, the last line is what you need, used for IE6-IE9.

You may want to include first line too, for older browsers (IE5.5...) that do not handle Gradients.

---

**EDIT**

Add the filter part in javascript too, after the other lines:

```
document.getElementById("gradient").style.filter = 
         "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(startColorstr='"+
                 color1+"', endColorstr='"+color2+"')"
```

And, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131356/filter-progiddximagetransform-microsoft-gradient-is-not-working-in-ie7), be sure to set `overflow: auto` or to set an height to your object.

---

**EDIT #2**

You are right, it will break with the other properties (with in CSS does not affect it).

Then check if it's IE, and use this JS:

```
document.getElementById("gradient").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient").startColorstr = color1;
document.getElementById("gradient").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient").endColorstr = color2;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll add it, but the gradient itself works fine, it's just my change function which doesn't work in older versions.

Comment: What ? Do you have javascript errors ? Just add the "filter" part to the javascript too, not only to the CSS, and you will be fine

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried your extra js line, but no luck. Nothing happens in older IE versions.

Comment: I tested it in IE8 with the latest javascript posted :|